# MVC3 Client Side Validation not working with an Ajax.BeginForm form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have the following form in a partial view

```
@model PartDetail
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Part", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =       "update_panel"}))
{
    <h3>New @Model.PartType</h3>
    <p> Serial Number: 
        <strong>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p> Name: 
        <strong>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </strong>
    </p>
    ...... more relatively boiler plate code here......
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Save Part"/>
    </p>
}
```

With a model of

```
public class PartDetail
{
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And I reference (in parent views of my partial view)

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

And nothing gets validated.  If I type nothing into the Serial Number text box and press submit it saves it to the database with no problems.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try adding an **OnBegin** callback to the AjaxOptions and this should work.

```
function validateForm() { 
   return $('form').validate().form(); 
} 

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Part", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", OnBegin = "validateForm" }))
...
```

If this doesn't work for you, an **alternative solution** may be to submit the form using jQuery. This would be my preferred solution.

```
<div id="result"></div> 

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
<h3>New @Model.PartType</h3>
<p>Serial Number: 
    <strong>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        </strong>
    </p>
    <p> Name: 
        <strong>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </strong>
    </p>
    ...... more relatively boiler plate code here......
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Save Part"/>
    </p>

    }
```

**jQuery/JS function to submit the form**

```
    $(function () { 
        $('form').submit(function () { 

        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));  //added

            if ($(this).valid()) { 
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: this.action, 
                    type: this.method, 
                    data: $(this).serialize(), 
                    success: function (result) { 
                        $('#result').html(result); 
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
            return false; 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: The top of my partial view now looks like this and it is still not validating....<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        return $('form').validate().form();
    } 
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Part", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "update_panel", OnBegin = "validateForm" }))
{

Comment: Stick an alert('test'); in validateForm() to see whether it is hit at all.

Comment: I updated my answer with a jQuery style solution. Although it doesn't address the problem you're experiencing, I prefer to use jQuery over Ajax and thought I'd give you the option here.

Comment: Let me implement that and give it a try.  My main goal is for it to function reliably.  Whatever technology it takes to do that is a secondary concern.

Comment: You'll need to specify the post URL - just noticed I hadn't specified it in my example (e.g. /Part/Create)

Comment: I implemented that verbatim (except I change '#result' to #update_panel) and it submits the form and acts as before with no validation.  I'm obviously missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Try running $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form')); after submitting

Comment: Updated my answer above with this in place.

Comment: That did it!!  ($.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));)  Thanks for your persistence.

Answer (score 3):

In this case order of javascript file including process is important. Your order of including these file should be

```
jquery.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

When I tried with re-ordering it works fine for me. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your root Web.config of the solution/project. Does it contain the following lines?

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>
```

It not, add them.

Comment: Yes it does.  I should have mentioned that I checked that as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to modified your controller action little bit to work validation in Ajax request 
you catch RenderHtml of partial view and apply your validation on it for e.g

```
    //In Controller 



     public string Create(PartDetail model)
        {
            string RenderHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("PartailViewName", model);
            return RenderHtml;
        }



protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
                viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

you must be pass ViewName and Model to **RenderPartialViewToString** method. it will return you view with validation which are you applied in model.