# ASP. NET MVC 3 Unobtrusive client validation not always work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've only recently started learning ASP.NET MVC 3 and already faced with such problem. I'm trying to use unobtrusive client validation in my project and there is strange thing about it. Here is code:

The first .cshtml file:

```
@model Task_2.Models.Worker
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Edit:";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit:</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CausesValidation/Validation.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Worker</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.worker_id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Second_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Second_Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Second_Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Profession)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Profession,
              (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ProfessionList"])
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Profession)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
    </div>
     <div class = "display-label">Projects:</div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <table>
            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<string>)ViewData["WorkerTasks"])
            {
                 <tr>
                 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item)</td>
                 </tr>   
            }
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("EditTasks", "EditTasks", new { id = Model.worker_id })
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"  name="Button_Edit_Worker"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

And here is a model class for it:

```
public partial class Worker
{
    public Worker()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    }
    [Key]
    public System.Guid worker_id { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-ZА-ЯЁ][A-ZА-ЯЁa-zа-яё .()-]*$", 
          ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Некорректный ввод!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }


    [RegularExpression(@"[A-ZА-Я][A-ZА-ЯЁЁa-zа-яё .()-]*$",
    ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Некорректный ввод!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [RegularExpression(@"[A-ZА-ЯЁ][A-ZА-ЯЁa-zа-яё .()-]*$", 
      ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Некорректный ввод!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public string Second_Name { get; set; }

    public string Profession { get; set; }



    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*$", 
      ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите корректное число")]  
    [Range(16,100,ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите число от 16 до 100")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}    
}
```

The second .cshtml file:

```
@model Task_2.Models.Task

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit:</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CausesValidation/Validation.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Задание:</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.task_id)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tusk_Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Task_Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tusk_Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    @ViewBag.message


    @if (ViewBag.source != "null")
    {
        <div>
          @Html.ActionLink("Back to task list of the current worker", 
          "EditTasks","Worker", new { id = new Guid(ViewBag.source) }, new { })
        </div>
    }

   <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>

</fieldset>
}
```

And a model class for it:

```
public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Workers = new HashSet<Workers>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int task_id { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"[A-ZА-ЯЁa-zа-яЁ0-9 .:()-]*$", 
     ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Некорректный ввод!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public string Tusk_Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]//, ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Некорректный ввод!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ошибка! Введите данные!")]
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}
```

and I've used js file from here:
[MVC3 Client Side Validation not working with an Ajax.BeginForm form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894764/mvc3-client-side-validation-not-working-with-an-ajax-beginform-form)

```
alert("hello");
$(function () {
$('form').submit(function () {

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));  //added
    alert("profit");
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                $('#result').html(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

from the answer about Html.BeginForm().

So, the problem is that when I'm trying to submit the first form, it only alerts "hello" and posting. Server-side validation works correctly and it shoes error messages, but it ignores alert("profit") and whole client validation completely. The second form works correctly and fires client-side validation on submitting. The questions are: where is mistake and how I can force client-side validation work correctly?

Comment: this may or may not help your issue here, but you want to generally parse your ajax form from $.validator.unobtrusive.parse on load, rather than when it submits.

Comment: So what shall I do? I've already tried @Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Tasks", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "something" }), it's not working, and I've no idea what else can be done.

Comment: I have a script somewhere here that helps out with this and a post on here related to this, I'll try to find in just a bit, have some work things going on right now.

Comment: If you do, it'll be very good. Thank you very much for interest to my problem.

Comment: One more intersting thing is that alert ("profit") on the second page works without any troubles, so the mistake probably somewhere in the first part of code...

Comment: check out my posting at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825631/asp-net-mvc-can-you-use-data-annotations-validation-with-an-ajax-jquery-cal

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! I've placed all my content into named div and then add code from your answer - that's a solution. Thank you for you kind attention, I hope this solution can help someone else.)

Comment: cool, I added below, please accept as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my posting here, I have some code that will help in the ajax updating/validation parsing:

[ASP.Net MVC: Can you use Data Annotations / Validation with an AJAX / jQuery call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825631/asp-net-mvc-can-you-use-data-annotations-validation-with-an-ajax-jquery-cal)